Horror movie involving characters that cannot die and psalm 23
Some time ago I saw a horror movie that involved two kids (a girl and her younger brother). I believe it was some lesser known film that wouldn't have been widely advertised (particularly since I cannot find it with all my creative googling). I saw it on DVD, so it might not have been in theatres. I can't remember anything about the language or year.
Some defining features include:

The girl recited psalm 23 a lot ("the lord is my shephard; I shall not want").
The victims of the main villain were revealed to have not died, but rather be stuck in some sort of state of limbo, where they had their gorey wounds that should have killed them, yet they weren't dead.
The boy survives in the end but the girl doesn't.
I believe that most of the events occurred within a movie. ie, they were trapped in a film, with only the boy managing to escape.


Sounds like Midnight Movie from 2008.

At a run down theater in a sleepy suburban town, a group of friends attend the midnight screening of a 1970s cult horror film. These unsuspecting teenagers are unaware that the director and star of the movie made a bloody escape from a psych ward five years earlier and may still be on the loose.
As the midnight movie begins, the kids heckle the old black-and-white scenes. But they are jolted when the killer butchers one of their friends...on screen! They soon realize that the killing is not a prank. They are locked inside the theatre and the killer from the movie is after them!
Caught between reality and the screen's flickering shadows, are they becoming the unwilling stars of the very horror movie they are watching?

Everything you've described (the killer's wounded victims stuck in movie limbo, the constant reciting of psalm 23, the girl sacrificing herself in the end to save the boy) is there. Here's the trailer:




Spot on, thanks. I'd forgotten that there was other characters besides the two children.
